# Modifying one line in Iptables

Tags: debian, iptables

How would one modify the following line in iptables file (debian)?

```
ACCEPT     all  --  XXX.XXX.XX.X         anywhere            PHYSDEV match --physdev-in vif3.1
```

TO

```
ACCEPT     all  --  YYY.YYY.YY.Y         anywhere            PHYSDEV match --physdev-in vif3.1
```

I looked up the h[ttps://wiki.debian.org/iptables](https://wiki.debian.org/iptables)
and I'm having hard time figuring out how to exactly do this modification.
Can it be done using one command, or there is a way to temporally "extract" the iptables file and modify it using nano or vi, and put it back in place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To replace that particular rule using `iptables` you need to do some debugging first.

First option is replacing the rule instantly.

1) See what line-number and in what CHAIN the mentioned line is placed. e.g:

```
iptables -L -v -n --line-n
```

2) Locate the line and replace it based on the output.

```
iptables -R [CHAIN_NAME] [LINE_NUMBER] -s YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY -m physdev  --physdev-in vif3.1  -j ACCEPT
```

Second option is to save the iptables rules and modify the file and import it.

1) Save the rules.

```
iptables-save > my_ipt-$(date +%F).ipt
```

2) Modify the my_ipt-$(date +$F).ipt

3) import the `my_ipt-$(date +%F).ipt`

```
iptables-restore < my_ipt-$(date +%F).ipt
```

NOTE: `$(date +%F)` is the date you saved the file e.g:  2013-11-07

Check if everything is as expected

```
iptables -L -v -n --line-n
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible :
`iptables -L CHAIN -n -v --line-numbers` give you the index in the rules
`iptables -S CHAIN INDEX` display the rule

Edit With 
-R CHAIN INDEX parameters.

Exemple :
`iptables -L Visioconf-OUT -n -v --line-numbers`

```
Chain Visioconf-OUT (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1     719K   49M LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "DROP4 Visioconf-OUT "
2     719K   49M DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

`iptables -S Visioconf-OUT 2`

> -A Visioconf-OUT -j DROP

`iptables -R Visioconf-OUT 2 -s 1.2.3.4 -j DROP`